# Chapter page spanning left and right side

Tags: graphics, sectioning, chapters, eso-pic

I am working on a document in which I would like to have a picture with chapter number on the left side and on the right the chapter number and title of the chapter.

When having the chapter on the right side, when adding the chapter number command for the left page it is always of by 1 chapter as it most likely uses the number of the previous chapter.

When starting on the left side I am unable to move the title text to the next page.

Here are some code snippets I currently use:

```
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\BackgroundPic{
    \put(0,0){
    \parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
    \vfill
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{Figures/Generic/chapter_page.pdf}
    \vfill
}}}
```

and

```
\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
  \hbox{}
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \AddToShipoutPicture*{\BackgroundPic}
  \begin{center}
    \thechapter %This page intentionally contains only this sentence.
  \end{center}
  \vspace{\fill}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
  \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I would define a `\newcounter{nextchapter}` and in the `\cleardoublepage` (is it really the good place do to all this stiff ?) `\setcounter{nextchapter}{\thechapter}
\stepcounter{nextchapter}`and then use `\thenextchapter` instead of `thechapter `

Comment: Instead of code snippets, how about providing a complete document that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and exactly what your problem is? As it stands, it's difficult to understand what you mean by left and right side of the page... this could mean a single page, or a spread of 2 pages in a `twoside` document. Don't just answer my comment in another comment, but provide a complete document instead.